# PHP: output xml contents

Tags: php, xml

Can someone please help me work out how to output the below XML file in PHP

```
    XML:
    <student>
    <name>studentname</name>
    <map>
    <competency>
      <level>5</level>
      <skill name="Maths"> 
         <skillinfo> "some value" </skillinfo>
      </skill>
    <competency>
  <competency>
      <level>4</level>
      <skill name="Science"> 
         <skillinfo> "some value" </skillinfo>
      </skill>
    <competency>
  <competency>
      <level>5</level>
      <skill name="Technology"> 
         <skillinfo> "some value" </skillinfo>
      </skill>
    <competency>
    </map>
    </student>

Code I've so far:

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($data);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$x = $dom->documentElement;

    echo "<table class='blueTable' >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Skill</th>
      <th>Level</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr> ";
    foreach ($xpath->query('//skill') as $item) {
        foreach($item->parentNode->childNodes as $node)
        if ($node->tagName == 'level')
             echo "<td>" . $node->nodeValue . "</td>";
    }
```

The above code outputs all the levels found in the XML file for that student. Each student has their own XML file, but you don't need to worry about that complexity. Lets work out how to output just one student, their skill and level first.

I'm using XDOM and what I'd like to do is:

In a table I'd like list first the student name, skill name (maths), and the level information. This needs to be iterated as there are multiple skills and levels within each skill for each student.

I can work out how to find something via XPATH and then locate its parent but can't seem to figure out how to loop this properly. Please help :)

Thank you

Comment: Can you add what you have tried to your question?

Comment: where are the codes? and why do you need a loop? are there multiple student nodes in there? the xml above only shows 1

Comment: @Ghost I assume he means loop over 'multiple skills and levels' although an example of this data would be useful.

Comment: @NigelRen or probably multiple competency nodes, we don't know yet, only the OP does

Comment: No there is only one student however each student has several Skill and each skill with varying skill level. I will update the question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to get your values. The elements are or type SimpleXMLElement and you could use `(string)` to get the value. You might use this to create your table.

```
$studentName = (string)$elm->name;
echo $studentName . "<br>";
foreach ($elm->map->competency as $comp) {
    $level = (string)$comp->level;
    $name = (string)$comp->skill->attributes()->name;
    $skillinfo = (string)$comp->skill->skillinfo;
    echo sprintf(
        "level: $level: %s<br> name: %s<br> skillinfo: %s",
        $level, $name, $skillinfo
    );
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6PMeR)

Comment: no need for xpath, just use `SimpleXML` and access attributes and stuff + 1

Comment: @Ghost Of course, you are right. I have updated the code.

Comment: Thank you! (string) was the key I needed to know.